# Bokeh Error Invalid calling object in IE 11

Tags: python, internet-explorer-11, bokeh

This is my code :

[image]

That code works perfectly well on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but while using IE11 I get this error:

> Bokeh Error Invalid calling object

What can be the reason?

Comment: this is my code:

from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
df['x']=[1,2,3,4,5]
df['y']=[5,4,7,9,3]
p=Scatter(df,x="x",y="y")
output_file('C:\data\Scatter_charts.html')
show(p)

Comment: Has this been resolved? I seem to have the same issue and would appreciate to know what the update has been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by upgrading bokeh to 0.12.6 and above version.